# c# File.WriteAllLines new line backslash

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list which I am trying to write to a file using `File.WriteAllLines()`. One of the strings in the list is from a `richTextBox` and hence contains `\n` for new lines. But `writeAllLines` seems to interpret that as write on a new line as if it was a separate item in the string list. I have inspected my code and can see that the string makes it to the final write all lines part of my code before being split up. I have also tried using the `'@'` sign in the string and that has also not worked.

Does anyone know how to make `writeAllLines` ignore escape sequences?

Comment: `WriteAllLines` *does* ignore escape sequences. I'm pretty certain that your line *really* contains a linebreak, which might be shown as `\n` in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want each entry in the file to be on one line. So the problem is that one or more of the strings that you are writing to the file contain line breaks, which are written to the file in addition to the line breaks that WriteAllLines writes out.

The only way out is that you programmatically escape the line breaks of WriteAllLines' input data. Do this for each value that could contain line breaks.

```
string escapedValue = originalValue.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n");
```

When reading back in the file, you will need to unescape each line.

```
string unescapedValue = escapedValue.Replace("\\r", "\r").Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Please note: The code sample is not perfect. If the original strings contain backslashes followed by 'r' or 'n', the unescape logic will convert them to line breaks. You will probably have to escape '\' characters as well to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue!

Comment: Loading = content.Replace("\\n", "\n").Replace("\\r", "\r").Replace("~","\\");

Comment: Saving = content.Replace("\\", "~").Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r"));

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` in the text from `richTextBox` is *not* an escape sequence, it is an actual `<LF>` character. It may look like `\n` in the debugger, but the string contains a single character at the corresponding position.

Imagine that you need to write a comma-separated list of strings to a file, and one of the strings contains a comma:

```
"quick,brown", "fox", "jumps"
```

The list would be written out as follows

```
quick,brown,fox,jumps
```

and there would be no way to find out which comma came from a string.

You can work around the issue by replacing `\n` with some other character when writing the file, and then replacing it back when reading it.

```
// Writing
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\lines.txt", lines.Select(s => s.Replace('\n', '~')));

// Reading back
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\lines.txt")
    .Select(s => s.Replace('~', '\n')))
    .ToArray();
```

Note that the character that you choose must not be present anywhere else in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Given this list:

```
var lines = new List<string>(3) {
    "Here's a line",
    "Line \n with a newline character",  // \n here is a newline character
    "Line with a \r character"  // \r here is a carriage return character
};
```

To get your text file to read like this:

> ```
> Here's a line
> Line \n with a newline character
> Line with a \r character
> ```

You would want to do something like this:

```
var escapedLines =  lines.Select(l => l.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r")).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", escapedLines);
```